# React - setting input prop from defaultValue to value triggers infinite loop

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a container component that has a child component `TranslateForm` where I have a form, and a it's child component `AnswersTranslation`.
In container component I have a a function `changeTranslation` that I am sending down with props:

```
  async changeTranslation(event, language) {
    const translationToUpdate = this.state.translations.find(translation => translation.languageCode === language);

    if (event.target.name === 'task') {
      translationToUpdate.taskText.to = event.target.value;
    } else {
      translationToUpdate.answers[event.target.name].to = event.target.value
    }

    this.setState({translations: this.state.translations.map(translation => translation.languageCode === language ? translationToUpdate : translation)});

    this.handleApiCall({...translationToUpdate});
 }

 handleApiCall(body) {
    if (this.timer !== null) {
      clearTimeout(this.timer);
    }

    this.timer = setTimeout(async () => {
      this.setState({saving: true});
      this.timer = null;
      await this.gateway.changeTranslation(body, this.props.match.params);
      this.setState({saving: false});
    }, 300);
}
```

And I am sending it down like a prop:

```
onChange={(event, language) => this.changeTranslation(event, language)}
```

`TranslateForm` has a form that triggers onKeyCapture events:

```
<form id={`translate-${translate}`} onKeyUpCapture={event => onChange(event, language)} autoComplete="off">
 <AnswersTranslation props={...props} />
</form>
```

`AnswersTranslation` component has an input field where I was previously setting a `defaultValue` like this:

```
                   {answers.map((answer, index) => {
                         <Input
                            name={`${index}`}
                            placeholder="Translate..."
                            className={classes.input}
                            defaultValue={answers[translate] !== null ? answers[translate] : ''}
                            disableUnderline={true}
                            inputProps={{
                                'aria-label': `answer-tekst-`,
                                maxLength: 100,
                            }}
                            disabled={translate === 'from'}
                        />
                    }
```

That worked fine, but it didn't update the value of the Input field, so I instead of setting defaultValue I set the value like this:

```
value={answers[translate] !== null ? answers[translate] : ''}
```

But, once I did that I got the error:

> Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component
>   repeatedly calls setState inside componentWillUpdate or
>   componentDidUpdate. React limits the number of nested updates to
>   prevent infinite loops.

Why is this happening?

Comment: How does `changeTranslation` look like?

Comment: I will add it to the question

Comment: Does the issue still happen if you remove the timeout from `handleApiCall`?

Comment: @Clarity yes, I get the same error

Answer (score 0):

The issue might be because when you're getting the `translationToUpdate`, it still keeps the reference to the state, so basically you're directly modifying it. Try to use functional form of `setState` and call `handleApiCall` as a callback, where the value from the state will be retrieved:

```
async changeTranslation(event, language) {
  const { name, value } = event.target;

  this.setState(state => ({
    translations: state.translations.map(translation => {
      if (translation.languageCode === language) {
        return name === 'task' ? {
          ...translation,
          taskText: {
            ...translation.taskText,
            to: value
          }
        } : {
          ...translation,
          answers: {
            ...translation.answers,
            [name]: value
          }
        }
      }
      return translation
    })
  }), () => this.handleApiCall(language)); // Callback after the state is set
}

handleApiCall = (language) => {
  const body = this.state.translations.find(translation => translation.languageCode === language);

  if (this.timer !== null) {
    clearTimeout(this.timer);
  }

  this.timer = setTimeout(async () => {
    this.setState({
      saving: true
    });
    this.timer = null;
    await this.gateway.changeTranslation(body, this.props.match.params);
    this.setState({
      saving: false
    });
  }, 300);
}
```